# Unexpected behavior with simple Swift code

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I'm trying to get a var to get an array's value mirroring its position. Then divide it by another var's value getting it from another array mirroring its position. Then assign the result value to a third var.

Now, in a function I increment the 1st var by 1 and then append the resulting value to a third array.
Or so I thought.

It adds a value that is the simple division of the first two vars without incrementing the first var.
But in the console the result of the 3rd var (holding the division's result), it shows the increment.
It's only in the append part of the function that it doesn't take it into account.

I'm sure it's a syntax problem but I'd be really thankful if anyone could look at my code.

```
import UIKit

var positionA = 3
var positionB = 1
var arrayA = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var arrayB = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var arrayPosition = arrayA[positionA] / arrayB[positionB]
var arrayOfValues = [ 0 ,1 , 2, 3, 4]

print(arrayOfValues[1])
print(arrayOfValues[arrayPosition])

func increment() {
    positionA = positionA + 1
    arrayOfValues.append(positionA)
}

increment()

print(positionA)
print(arrayOfValues)
print(" ads a value of 4 to the arrayOfValues ( equal to positionA + 1) ")

func incrementB() {
    positionA = positionA + 1
    arrayOfValues.append(arrayPosition)
}

incrementB()

print(positionA)
print(arrayOfValues)
print("adds a value of 3 to the arrayOfValues that it still is equal to positionA, WITHOUT adding a +1 in the calculation of arrayPosition, when it SHOULD ADD a value of 5( positionA + 1 from increment(), +1 from incrementB) ")
```

Comment: Please give a concise list of these three things: the input values, the output you expect, and the output you actually get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrayPosition is never changed after its initial assignment ( with a value of 3 resulting from 3 / 1 ).

Although positionA will indeed be 5 after the 2nd increment, that's not what you're adding to your arrayOfValues so the result is as expected (3).

[EDIT]

You could make it a computed variable like this

```
var arrayPosition : Int { return arrayA[positionA] / arrayB[positionB] }
```

It's just like a function but you don't need to use () to call it.

Comment: hi Alain thanx for the answer, i see from the resulting that the arrayPosition gets the same value of the first calculation (3) but shouldn't incremented?

Comment: arrayPosition is a variable, not a function.   You would need to assign a new value to the variable to make it change.

Comment: hi Alain thanx for the answer, i see from the resulting that the arrayPosition gets the same value of the first calculation (3) but shouldn't incremented so pass a 5 ?
if i change
 arrayOfValues.append(arrayPosition) for arrayOfValues.append(arrayA[positionA] / arrayB[positionB])
it then works..
i thought that positionA would pass it's new value of 5 in the arrayPosition declaration..

mm lots of thoughts about this..but would you explain why?
many thanks for helping me out 
very thankful for it

Comment: mmmm i actually tought of changing it into a function as i kinda smelled that was the problem but eventually i didn't do it righ.. i'll try again after coffee ..

Comment: hi again. i understood that by making arrayPosition computable it will actually perform the increment inside te function, and if a was to declare it the normal way i had to declare it again inside the body of the function.. eighter way would work.

now.. i'm trying to assign to the var calculation the value of the computed arrayPosition and use calculation to perform the append.. but still it works only if i declare it inside the body of the function .. so i'm trying to make this computable as well with 
var calculation : Int { return calculation = arrayPosition }

Comment: hi guys and first of all many thanks for helping out a novice like me..

is there a way to call arrayPosition and get  arrayA[positionA] and arrayB[positionB] as values?
i thought of dictionaries..but i haven't touched it yet